# How to embed a mapview map in a Jupyter Notebook with IRkernel?

Tags: r, mapview, irkernel, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking to integrate some awesome [mapview](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview) interactive maps in a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) with the [IRkernel](https://irkernel.github.io/).

I would like to know if:

- Is it possible? How can I achieve that?
- Is there any workaround using Jupyter Notebook with IPython kernel using cell magics `%%`?

In a Jupyter Notebook cell, I tried:

```
# Load shapefile
shapefile <- sf::read_sf('../path/to/shapefile.shp')

# Plot mapview map
mapview::mapview(shapefile)
```

No luck, and no error message showed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- the R package [IRkernel](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/) and you are working in R

[image]

- the Python [Rmagic extension](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rmagic-a-handy-interface-bridging-python-and-r/) moved to  [rpy2](https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/) and you are working in Python but you can mix Python code and R code (see ee [fiona_gstat_essai1.ipynb](https://github.com/mlaloux/mesnotebooks/blob/master/fiona_gstat_essai1.ipynb), for example.)

[image]

#### New

It works without problem (library(maptools))

[image]

with the result in another tab

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort but unfortunately, I couldn't run a mapview map using your trick. I tried loading the `rpy2.ipython` extension but It didn't work. I don't know If I'm missing something. Did you try using `mapview`?

Comment: It works without problem, look above in New

Comment: thanks! Some problem don't let mapview work correctly: `Warning in R_ut_init: Error parsing unit specification`. Anyway, the question is answered.